# Pre-populated View data crashing the page, not posting, on submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, view, model

I am working on a survey of 8 questions. If I hard-code the question text on the .cshtml page, everything works fine. the form posts and writes to the database. But if I try to pre-populate the questions from the database into the view model, the form will no longer post. In fact, it just freezes and does nothing. My hope is to retrieve the questions from the database (which works fine), then populate the View with those questions (which also works) and still be able to submit the form (that does not work).

I'll post the code that was not working. Here is the view model:

```
 public class SurveyQuestionsViewModel
    {
        public SurveyAnswers Question1 { get; set; }
        public IList<Question2ViewModel> Question2Options { get; set; }
        public SurveyAnswers Question2 { get; set; }
        public string Question3a { get; set; }
        public string Question3b { get; set; }
        public string Question3c { get; set; }
        public SurveyAnswers Question3 { get; set; }
        public SurveyAnswers Question4 { get; set; }
        public SurveyAnswers Question5 { get; set; }
        public SurveyAnswers Question6 { get; set; }
        public SurveyAnswers Question7 { get; set; }
        public SurveyAnswers Question8 { get; set; }

        public IList<Question> Questions { get; set; }

        public SurveyQuestionsViewModel(List<Question> questions)
        {
            Question2Options = new[]
            {
                new Question2ViewModel { Name = "Option1" },
                new Question2ViewModel { Name = "Option2" },
                new Question2ViewModel { Name = "Option3" },
                new Question2ViewModel { Name = "Option4" }
            }.ToList();

            Questions = questions;
        }
    }
```

Here is the Action Method on the controller that populates the view model, which also works fine. The questions collection gets the correct data.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var questions = _surveyService.GetActiveQuestions();
            return View(new SurveyQuestionsViewModel(questions.ToList()));
        }
```

And here is the Question model, which makes up the Questions collection on the ViewModel:

```
 public class Question
    {
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    }
```

At this point the form will not post. To get it to post I need to remove all references to "Questions" in the code. Then it posts fine. But then I also need to hard-code the questions, which I would rather not do if I don't have to.

What I did on the View itself to populate the questions from the database was attempt to query the Questions collection by Id:

```
@Model.Questions.Where(q=>q.QuestionId == 1).Select(q=>q.QuestionText).FirstOrDefault()
```

This actually worked and the questions displayed from the database correctly to the ViewModel and onto the View. But when I pressed the "Submit" button, the page goes blank, the code does not progress to the ActionResult and I receive no errors whatsoever. Everything just stops.

I have a feeling that I'm just not handling the Questions collection properly on the view. I probably need to iterate through it in some way and perhaps give each element some HTML item to post to? I don't care if the questions actually post through the ViewModel to the ActionResult, but I would prefer to ignore them altogether after they display. Maybe it's just late in the day and the brain is tired, but so far I've found nothing that works.

Any ideas or thoughts would be appreciated! Thank you!

Receiving ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult AccountProfileRedirect(SurveyQuestionsViewModel surveyResponses)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _surveyService.TransformSurvey(surveyResponses);
            }

            return Redirect("~/AccountPage.aspx");
        }
```

To cut down on space, here is a portion of the view. This missing parts are just additional yes/no questions. It's probably not perfect, but it should give you the basic idea.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    ViewBag.Title = "Survey";
    var ID = ViewBag.ID ?? "0";
    var ID_INT = Int32.Parse(ID);
    var today = DateTime.Now;
    var LastRenewal = ViewBag.LastRenewal;
}
@model Comp.Public.Web.Areas.RenewalSurvey.Models.SurveyQuestionsViewModel
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/mainTemplate")
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/template")
    @Styles.Render("~/Areas/RenewalSurvey/Content/CSS/SurveyStyles.css")
</head>
<body>
    <div id="area_header">
        <div id="header_right">
            <div id="secondary_menu"><span class="secondary_menu"><a href="/Contact.aspx">Contact</a> / <a href="/Policies.aspx">Policies</a> / <a href="/Legal.aspx">Legal</a> </span></div>
            <div id="header_login">
                <uc2:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="~/" runat="server">
                <img src="@Url.Content("/images/logo.png")" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bar1"></div>
    <div id="bar2"></div>
    <div id="area_content">
        @{
            Html.RenderPartial("Menu");
        }
        <div class="area clear" style="margin: 20px auto">
            <div id="content_left" class="body" runat="server">
                <h3>@ViewBag.Title</h3>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("AccountProfileRedirect", "Survey", FormMethod.Post, new { id="surveyForm"}))
                {
                    <ol class="SurveyList">
                        <li class="SurveyList">
                            Question 1 Text
                            <div>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Question1.UserAnswer, false) No @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Question1.UserAnswer, true) Yes</div>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question1.QuestionId, new { Value = "1" })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question1.AnswerDate, new { Value = today })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question1.ID, new { Value = ID })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question1.ID_INT, new { Value = ID_INT })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question1.LastRenewal, new { Value = LastRenewal })

                        </li>
                        <li>Question 2 text
                            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Question2Options.Count; i++)
                            {
                                <div>
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Question2Options[i].Name)
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Question2Options[i].Checked)
                                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Question2Options[i].Checked, Model.Question2Options[i].Name)
                                </div>
                            }
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question2.QuestionId, new { Value = "2" })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question2.AnswerDate, new { Value = today })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question2.ID, new { Value = ID })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question2.ID_INT, new { Value = ID_INT })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question2.LastRenewal, new { Value = LastRenewal })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question2.UserAnswer)
                        </li>
                        <li>
Question 3 Text                            <div class="RankQuestion">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Question3a, Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString() })) Option1</div>
                            <div class="RankQuestion">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Question3b, new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1, 3))) Option2</div>
                            <div class="RankQuestion">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Question3c, new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1, 3))) Option3</div>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question3.QuestionId, new { Value = "3" })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question3.AnswerDate, new { Value = today })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question3.ID, new { Value = ID })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question3.ID_INT, new { Value = ID_INT })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question3.LastRenewal, new { Value = LastRenewal })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question3.UserAnswer)
                        </li>
                        <li>
                   Question 4 Text
                            <div>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Question4.UserAnswer, false) No @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Question4.UserAnswer, true) Yes</div>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question4.QuestionId, new { Value = "4" })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question4.AnswerDate, new { Value = today })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question4.ID, new { Value = ID })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question4.ID_INT, new { Value = ID_INT })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question4.LastRenewal, new { Value = LastRenewal })
                        </li>
</ol>
                    <input type="submit" name="submitAnswers" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitForm()" />
                }
                <a href="~/nextscreen.aspx">Return to Renewal</a>
            </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/survey")
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you paste the action that's receiving the form data? And the view

Comment: @0liveradam8 - updated, thank you!